# Kibana - Coordinate map - Filter coords using JSON input

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am working on a visualisation using Kibana and I have a special case, where I would like to hide/filter out some coordinates.
I am using the Coordinate map tool, each coordinate is a position where the image was taken.

Some of them have lat, lon = (0,0), which I would like to filter out using JSON Input.
The coordinates are stored like:

> 'image_location': '0, 0'

> 'image_location': '51.415311, 6.868105'

My code, it does not work:

```
{"filter" : [
   { "match" : { 
     "image_location": {"lat": 0,"lon": 0} 
               }
   }
            ]
}
```

[image]
Kibana version: Version: 6.2.3

Comment: The JSON input section is not meant to add queries. You can add a filter at the top (just below the search bar) to filter out those bad coordinates... or better yet, cleanse them at indexing time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try to figure out, how could I filter them adding it at the top...

Comment: Coordinate map allows for drawing spatial filters on the map. Draw a spatial filter around 0,0 location. This will add a filter pill under the search bar. Then click on the filter pill and select "Exclude results" to show everything not in the drawn area.